# Facing some Issues on Two Parts Custom Post Type Taxonomy Names

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I facing issues on creating custom Post Type and Taxonomy.

what should I name my Custom Taxonomy template? is `taxonomy-special_offer_type.php` correct name?

Is this the correct way of WP Query?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'special_offer', 'posts_per_page' => 500 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
endwhile;
```

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Special Offers')` is it a correct slug name?

What name i should use for my custom post type? i am using same name in both functions :

```
function cpt_special_offer() {
        $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Special Offers',
        'singular_name' => 'Special Offer',
        'menu_name' => 'Special Offers',
        'name_admin_bar' => 'Special Offers',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Special Offers:',
        'all_items' => 'All Special Offers',
        'view_item' => 'View Special Offers',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Special Offer',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Special Offer',
        'new_item' => 'New Special Offer',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Special Offer',
        'update_item' => 'Update Special Offer',
        'search_items' => 'Search Special Offer',
        'not_found' => 'Special Offer Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Special Offer Not found in Trash',
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Special Offers',
        'description' => 'This Post Type Adds Special Offers to Website',
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'special_offer' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Special Offers'),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'special_offer', $args );
} 
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_special_offer', 0 );

function tax_special_offer() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Special Offer Types',
        'singular_name' => 'Special Offer Type',
        'menu_name' => 'Special Offer Types',
        'all_items' => 'All Special Offer Types',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Special Offer Types',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Special Offer Types:',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Special Offer Type',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Special Offer Type',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Special Offer Type',
        'update_item' => 'Update Special Offer Type',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Special Offer Type with commas',
        'search_items' => 'Search Special Offer Type',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or Remove Special Offer Type',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used Special Offer Types',
        'not_found' => 'Special Offer Types Not Found',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'special_offer_type', array( 'special_offer' ), $args );
    }
add_action( 'init', 'tax_special_offer', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The slug refers to the url
eg
http://wwww.sitename.com//

so you want it to have no spaces and be in lower case
eg
special-offers